# Selenium remote WebDriver issue

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver

I am trying to do parallel execution using Selenium in my machine. I have configured hub and node successfully. But in my code, I am getting an error at remote web driver initialization.

My code:

```
 package com.selenium.gautham;
 import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test {
 @Test
    public static void sample()
    {
    DesiredCapabilities cap =DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    cap.setBrowserName("ie");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    RemoteWebDriver driver =RemoteWebDriver(new       URL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"),cap);
    driver.get(url);
    }}
```

I'm getting this error:

> The constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined

Where did I do wrong?

[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6lr.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your imports (before the start of the class), i haven't seen an import for the URL Class. I believe you are trying to use the below constructor of RemoteWebDriver Class.

```
RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL remoteAddress, Capabilities desiredCapabilities)
```

If so, i would suggest you to first try replacing the below line

```
    RemoteWebDriver driver =RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"),cap);
```

to the one below and see if its working fine.

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"), cap);
```

If you see the above alternative working then import

```
java.net.URL
```

Comment: added line, not getting any suggestions for importing java.net. I might have missed  jar files. Please suggest which jars to download

Comment: If you are looking for URL it is from the Java class. You should have got basic Java JRE jars with the creation of the Java project. For the other imports you should add the selenium server jar to your build path.

Comment: Added JRE Sysytem Library Jars and Standalone Server 2.52.0, still facing same issue. Checked many videos and everyone are using  RemoteWebDriver constructor. I am unable to use it.  Feeling helpless.    imported: import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver; import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL; and still getting "he method RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined"  and "java.net cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: code: if (sBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
DesiredCapabilities oCap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
oCap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true); 
driver = RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"), oCap);
} else if (sBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
DesiredCapabilities oCap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
driver =RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL("http://localhost:4444/wb/hub"), oCap);}

Comment: tried in new Project. Now i am not getting any error. Thanks a lot for your help. Now to execute in parallel i need to register hub and node right? Or without registering also using thread count in testng can i execute scripts in multiple browsers at a time????